# How to replace multiple strings in a Teradata select statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to select from a table, but remove various strings.
Let's say entries in my table are:

```
DataMart1:Here is some data and other valuable data
HouseWareMart Other data possibly junk data
DataLake3 there is nothing here
```

And I want to remove various strings:
    "Valuable data"
    "Other data "
    "there is nothing "

So I would get:

```
DataMart1:Here is some data and other
HouseWareMart possibly junk data
DataLake3 here
```

I thought about nesting OREPLACE, but couldn't get the syntax right, and searching 'Nested OREPLACE' returned nothing helpful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for nested replace:

```
select oreplace(oreplace(oreplace(col, 'Valuable data', ''), 'Other data ', ''), 'there is nothing ', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Caution: `oReplace` is case sensitive (`'Valuable data'` will not match `'valuable data'`) and might find a 2nd match after removing the 1st, e.g. `'DataLake3 there is valuable data nothing date'` removes `valuable data` first and then `there is nothing` from the remaining string.

A simler way to remove multiple strings utilizes `regexp_replace`, either case sensitive

```
RegExp_Replace(col, 'valuable data|other data|there is nothing')
```

or case insensitive

```
RegExp_Replace(col, 'valuable data|other data|there is nothing', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```